# call a rest service in google chrome extension

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I was wondering if there is a way to make a call to a rest service in google chrome extension. because the domain that I was trying to request is from different domain and it is giving me an cross domain origin policy error from google chrome.

Comment: The server you're calling to needs to have a different CORS configuration then, or you're out of luck.

Comment: I'm sure there are simple ways in chrome extension to avoid CORS issue - look in the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/xhr) and you'll find it

Comment: i guess that's it then. thanks ill look into it